# Associated type (type parameter) naming convention

Tags: rust, naming

[Rust's official naming guidelines](https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/naming.html) suggest that we should use concise `UpperCamelCase`, usually single uppercase letter: `T`.  But I have a trait with several associated types.  Is it okay to use acronyms such as `CD` to represent, say, connection data?  And I cannot use `C`, because it already exists (and also does not really portray "connection data").  I'd rather not use `ConnectionData` as that reads like a struct name.  Should I not do this?  I guess this question also applies to type parameters.

Comment: Do whatever makes sense and doesn't cause headache. A good comment in the source code is better than any official guideline

Comment: Thank you.  I guess the main reason I asked is I could not find this information in any other stackoverflow question.

Comment: For associated types, there is no problem: usually one writes `T::SomeAssocType` and it's clear *that* it is an associated type. For type parameters, I also often find the convention of using `T`, `U`, `V`… not the best, but I agree that naming them like structs can be confusing. As a compromise, I sometimes go for `TFoo`, `TBar`: prefix the name with a `T` to signal that it's a type parameter, but still give it a descriptive name.

Comment: That's true!  I think I will use your scheme of `TFoo`, etc.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where did you see that you should use shortcuts for associated types? They're commonly used for generic parameters (and even then, only when there is one or two), but not for associated types. Look in the standard library: there is no one-letter associated type. `ConnectionData` is the correct name.

Comment: In the shared link, it mentions camel case for type parameters.  I assumed same is the convention for associated types.  Thanks for the answer!  Counter question: is naming convention for associated types mentioned anywhere official?

Comment: @bkc4 Associated types do use UpperCamelCase (PascalCase), but not acronyms.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding.  In the link I shared in the main question, there is no entry for associated types.  BUT, there is an entry for type parameters, and it says: "Type parameters: concise UpperCamelCase, usually single uppercase letter: T."  Now I just assumed the same thing applies for associated types (so I asked this question how bad is to do, e.g., `CD`), which seems to be my mistake.

Comment: @bkc4 Well, no. As I said, look in the standard library.

Comment: Standard library could have just decided to not use single uppercase letters.

Comment: @bkc4 Standard library is the best place to look for naming conventions. Also, all popular crates I know also do that.

Comment: I understand.  Although, it would have been nice if it were mentioned in the linked RFC 430 directly instead.

Comment: @bkc4 Feel free to open an issue :)